# Язык программирование Си - вводы и выводы

Tags: c, вывод, ввод

в чем различия между getchar() и scanf("%c" , ...) ?

Comment: В данном случае `"%c"` -- разницы нет. Однако, в случае формата `" %c"` (обратите внимание на пробел перед %c) scanf будет передавать в программу только "непробельные" символы (т.е. все последовательные пробелы, табуляции, символы перевода строки и т.п. так называемые whitespace characters будут пропускаться.

Answer (score 0):

`Getchar` считывает один символ, а `scanf` считывает строку. Также `scanf` считывает ещё некоторые типы данных.

Comment: Вопрос про вполне конкретный scanf("c", из вашего ответа так и непонятно в чём разница

Comment: Разница в том, что функция getchar() просто считывает символ и больше ничего не делает, а значит её вызов работает эффективнее, чем вызов функции scanf("%c"), которой надо дополнительно анализировать переданную строку форматирования.

Answer (score 0):

Функциональность совпадает: обе функции читают следующий символ из `stdin`. Применение различается довольно сильно:

```
char c;
if (scanf("%c", &c) == 1) {
    process_char(c);
} else {
    process_error();
}

// getchar возвращает int чтобы вы могли получить значение EOF в случае ошибки
int c = getchar();
if (c == EOF) {
    process_error();
} else {
    process_char(c);
}
```

Производительность различается заметно. `scanf` - одна из самых дорогих функций, `getchar` - одна из самых быстрых.